# Handling 'no data' in Grafana subtraction query using LogQL with Loki

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, logql, grafana-dashboard

I'm using Promtail to forward logs to Loki and visualize the data with Grafana. I have a query that calculates the number of devices online without errors. The query works as follows:

```
(
  (count(count by(system) (count_over_time({job="mrs_error_list"} |~ "" [7d]))))
)
- 
(
  (count(count by(system) (count_over_time({job="mrs_error_list"} |~ "Error" [5m]))))
)
```

This works perfectly as long as both parts of the subtraction always have data. However, sometimes there are no error data in the last 5 minutes. When this happens, the entire subtraction evaluates to 'no data', but I'd prefer it to evaluate as subtracting zero.

What i tried:
I tried to use something like or vector(0), but this doesn't seem to exist yet for LogQL.
I attempted to use "Add field from calculation," but this returns the exact same error.
I tried to separate the query into two different ones and use the override option "Standard options > no value" so that it defaults to 0, but I can't subtract this value from the first query then.

What i am expecting:
I want the query to interpret 'no data' as zero, so the subtraction can still take place and yield a meaningful result in Grafana.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Premise in your question is incorrect. Loki supports constructions like `or vector(0)`, and it's even used in examples in [their documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/query/metric_queries/#functions).

So your query will look like this:

```
count(count by(system) (count_over_time({job="mrs_error_list"} |~ "" [7d])))
- 
(
  count(count by(system) (count_over_time({job="mrs_error_list"} |~ "Error" [5m])))
  or vector(0)
)
```

Alternatively, based on my answer to your previous question, you might count diference instead of subtracting counts:

```
count(
  count by(system) (count_over_time({job="mrs_error_list"} |~ "Timestamp" [7d]))
  unless
  count by(system) (count_over_time({job="mrs_error_list"} |~ "Timestamp" [1m]))
)
```

You can see couple live examples of similar queries [here](https://play.grafana.org/explore?panes=%7B%221S9%22:%7B%22datasource%22:%22ac4000ca-1959-45f5-aa45-2bd0898f7026%22,%22queries%22:%5B%7B%22refId%22:%22wo%20or%22,%22expr%22:%22count%28%5Cr%5Cn%20%20%20%20count%20by%20%28geoip_country_code%29%28%5Cr%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20count_over_time%28%7Bfilename%3D%5C%22%2Fvar%2Flog%2Fnginx%2Fjson_access.log%5C%22%7D%20%20%7C%20json%20%7Crequest_method%3D%5C%22POST%5C%22%5B1d%5D%29%5Cr%5Cn%20%20%20%20%29%29%5Cr%5Cn-%5Cr%5Cncount%28%5Cr%5Cn%20%20%20%20count%20by%20%28geoip_country_code%29%28%5Cr%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20count_over_time%28%7Bfilename%3D%5C%22%2Fvar%2Flog%2Fnginx%2Fjson_access.log%5C%22%7D%20%20%7C%20json%20%7Crequest_method%3D%5C%22POST%5C%22%20%5B1m%5D%29%5Cr%5Cn%20%20%20%20%29%29%22,%22queryType%22:%22range%22,%22datasource%22:%7B%22type%22:%22loki%22,%22uid%22:%22ac4000ca-1959-45f5-aa45-2bd0898f7026%22%7D,%22editorMode%22:%22code%22,%22hide%22:false,%22legendFormat%22:%22without%20or%22%7D,%7B%22refId%22:%22with%20or%22,%22expr%22:%22count%28%5Cr%5Cn%20%20%20%20count%20by%20%28geoip_country_code%29%28%5Cr%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20count_over_time%28%7Bfilename%3D%5C%22%2Fvar%2Flog%2Fnginx%2Fjson_access.log%5C%22%7D%20%20%7C%20json%20%7Crequest_method%3D%5C%22POST%5C%22%5B1d%5D%29%5Cr%5Cn%20%20%20%20%29%29%20-%20%28count%28%20count%20by%20%28geoip_country_code%29%28%5Cr%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20count_over_time%28%7Bfilename%3D%5C%22%2Fvar%2Flog%2Fnginx%2Fjson_access.log%5C%22%7D%20%20%7C%20json%20%7Crequest_method%3D%5C%22POST%5C%22%20%5B1m%5D%29%5Cr%5Cn%20%20%20%20%29%5Cr%5Cn%29%20or%20vector%280%29%29%22,%22queryType%22:%22range%22,%22datasource%22:%7B%22type%22:%22loki%22,%22uid%22:%22ac4000ca-1959-45f5-aa45-2bd0898f7026%22%7D,%22editorMode%22:%22code%22,%22hide%22:false,%22legendFormat%22:%22with%20or%22%7D,%7B%22refId%22:%22Alternative%20approach%22,%22expr%22:%22count%28%5Cr%5Cn%20%20%20%20count%20by%20%28geoip_country_code%29%28%5Cr%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20count_over_time%28%7Bfilename%3D%5C%22%2Fvar%2Flog%2Fnginx%2Fjson_access.log%5C%22%7D%20%20%7C%20json%7Crequest_method%3D%5C%22POST%5C%22%20%5B1d%5D%29%5Cr%5Cn%20%20%20%20%29%20unless%20count%20by%20%28geoip_country_code%29%28%5Cr%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20count_over_time%28%7Bfilename%3D%5C%22%2Fvar%2Flog%2Fnginx%2Fjson_access.log%5C%22%7D%20%20%7C%20json%7Crequest_method%3D%5C%22POST%5C%22%20%5B1m%5D%29%5Cr%5Cn%20%20%20%20%29%5Cr%5Cn%29%22,%22queryType%22:%22range%22,%22datasource%22:%7B%22type%22:%22loki%22,%22uid%22:%22ac4000ca-1959-45f5-aa45-2bd0898f7026%22%7D,%22editorMode%22:%22code%22,%22hide%22:false,%22legendFormat%22:%22alternative%22%7D%5D,%22range%22:%7B%22from%22:%22now-6h%22,%22to%22:%22now%22%7D%7D%7D&schemaVersion=1&orgId=1).

Comment: Thank you. I had to update my Grafana image from grafana/grafana-enterprise:9.4.3 to grafana/grafana-enterprise:10.1.5. Now I can use vector(0). Both of your suggested solutions work now.